# Run multiple TECs in series or at multi-channel TEC controller?

Tags: temperature, series

Assume we want to drive multiple thermoelectric coolers (Peltier elements) to control the temperature of a lab setup. To accommodate for the size and shape of the device to be cooled/heated we have to place a total of 12 TECs. They will - driven by the layout - be connected in series as groups of six. Polarity is being taken into account of course. The device will carry only one temperature sensor. Max. voltage per TEC is 0.9 V and controllers with output voltage exceeding 20 V are available, so that this should not be an issue.

The question is now whether it is preferable to use a dual-channel TEC controller to drive each group separately or to connect all twelve in series? Always assuming that the TEC controller can cover the necessary voltage range and total output power.

Side note: I understand that a series connection of all TECs will lead to a failure of the whole system as soon as one TEC breaks. However we assume that a repair would be due in such a case anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have issues with current sharing when you put things in parallel. I know this is a big problem for LEDs and I presume you will have even worse problems with TECs.  You should either add series resistors to force a more even split, or use a dual channel driver.  If you have a good, high efficiency driver, I would recommend using a dual channel driver as it will be more efficient.

Comment: Yes, this is actually the issue I am aware of. That is also why we connect things in series and not in parallel. As far as I understand it dual-channel TEC controllers provide two separate power stages so that driving the TEC that would should not be "in parallel". Please clarify if I am mistaken. Thanks.

Comment: They darn well better provide two output drivers, otherwise I don't think you can really call it a dual channel unit.

Comment: Now, 12 series vs dual channel controller with chains of 6 is a different issue. Depending on the TEC voltage, it may be difficult to find a controller that will put out enough volts to drive 12 in series.

Comment: Max. voltage per TEC is 0.9 V (they're quite small), controllers with output voltage exceeding 20 V are available, so that this should not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Discussing the issue with an engineering consultant who happens to design and manufacture TEC controllers we've come to the conclusion that there are no drawbacks to operate this 12 TECs in series connection with one single-channel controller.

For future reference: An improved mode of control is expected for the two-channel solution if the temperature distribution is inhomogeous.